# One to one relationship Mysql EF6

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

Hi there I've been banging my head now for two days and haven't been able to solve this one: I have this data structure:

```
[
  {
    "LocalObservationDateTime": "2019-12-12T19:50:00+02:00",
    "EpochTime": 1576173000,
    "WeatherText": "Thunderstorm",
    "WeatherIcon": 15,
    "HasPrecipitation": true,
    "Reciprocation": "Rain",
    "IsDayTime": false,
    "Temperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 13.7,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 57,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    } 
  }
]
```

I designed my data like this:

## Table1:

```
Id,
LocalObservationDateTime,
EpochTime
WeatherText,
WeatherIcon,
HasPrecipitation,
PrecipitationType,
IsDayTime,
TemperatureId
```

## Table2

```
TemperatureId,
ImperialId,
MetricId
```

## Table3

```
Id,
Value,
Unit,
UnitType
```

I connected FKs tables 3 Id `ImperialId` and `MetricId` in Table 3 and TemperatureId in Table 2 to TemperatureId in table1

these are my models:

```
[Table("currentweather")]
    public class CurrentWeather
    {
        [Key, Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
       [Column("locationid")]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [Column("localobservationdatetime")]
        public DateTime LocalObservationDateTime { get; set; }
         [Column("epochtime")]
        public long EpochTime { get; set; }
        [Column("weathertext")]
        public string WeatherText { get; set; }
        [Column("weathericon")]
        public int WeatherIcon { get; set; }
         [Column("hasprecipitation")]
        public bool HasPrecipitation { get; set; }
       [Column("precipitationtype")]
       public string PrecipitationType { get; set; }
        [Column("isdaytime")]
        public bool IsDayTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Temperature")]
        [Column("temperatureid")]
        public int TemperatureId { get; set; }       

        [Column("mobilelink")]
        public string MobileLink { get; set; }
        [Column("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Temperature Temperature { get; set; }

    }



[Table("temperature")]
    public class Temperature
    {
        [Key, Column("tepmeratureid")]
        public int TemperatureId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Imperial")]
        [Column("imperialid")]
        public int ImperialId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Metric")]
        [Column("metricid")]
        public int MetricId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public CurrentWeather CurrentWeather { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public TemperatureUnit Imperial { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public TemperatureUnit Metric { get; set; }
    }

    public class TemperatureUnit
    {

        public double Value { get; set; }
        public Unit Unit { get; set; }

        public int UnitType { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public Temperature Temperature { get; set; }

    }

    public enum Unit { C,F}
```

I am using Mysql and Net.core EF6

When adding data only table 1 gets the data but the other two don't HELP!!!

Comment: Your Navigation Properties should not be annotated as [NotMapped].

Comment: How are you adding the data? Are you trying to project that json formatted object onto a specific model? If so, you have to have a model that exactly matches the json formatted object, or have some way to map the properties over.

Comment: I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and then  _dataContext.CurrentWeather.Add(weather);    thejson gets serialized fine thers no problem there. th e proble is that when writing to db only main table gets the data

Answer (score 0):

Your json object doesn't match your database tables, so you'll have to do some mapping of those properties.

Note: the below code leaves off several properties, but you should be able to follow this and add them in as needed.

First, you need to make your json string into an object. If passed in from a controller you can use model binding; otherwise you'll have to deserialize it. Here's an appropriate view model for that:

```
 public class CurrentWeatherViewModel
    {
        public DateTime LocalObservartionTime { get; set; }
        public int EpochTime { get; set; }
        public string WeatherText { get; set; }
        //additional props here


        public TemperatureViewModel Temperature { get; set; }
    }



    public class TemperatureViewModel
    {
        public MetricViewModel Metric { get; set; }
        public ImperialViewModel Imperial { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetricViewModel
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public int UnitType { get; set; }
    }
    public class ImperialViewModel
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public int UnitType { get; set; }
    }
```

You can deserialize the json string into that object like this:

```
var jsonString = " {\"EpochTime\": 1576173000,\"WeatherText\": \"Thunderstorm\",\"WeatherIcon\": 15,\"HasPrecipitation\": true,\"Reciprocation\": \"Rain\",\"IsDayTime\": false,\"Temperature\": {\"Metric\": {\"Value\": 13.7,\"Unit\": \"C\",\"UnitType\": 17},\"Imperial\": {\"Value\": 57,\"Unit\": \"F\",\"UnitType\": 18}}}";

CurrentWeatherViewModel currentWeatherViewModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentWeatherViewModel>(jsonString);
```

Once it's deserialized into the viewmodel object, you can create your entities and save them to the db:

```
 CurrentWeather currentWeather = new CurrentWeather
            {
                WeatherText = currentWeatherViewModel.WeatherText,
                Temperature = new Temperature
                {
                    Measurements = new Measurement[] {
                        new Measurement {
                            Unit = currentWeatherViewModel.Temperature.Metric.Unit,
                            UnitType = currentWeatherViewModel.Temperature.Metric.UnitType,
                            Value = currentWeatherViewModel.Temperature.Metric.Value,
                        },
                        new Measurement {
                            Unit = currentWeatherViewModel.Temperature.Imperial.Unit,
                            UnitType = currentWeatherViewModel.Temperature.Imperial.UnitType,
                            Value = currentWeatherViewModel.Temperature.Imperial.Value,
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            db.CurrentWeathers.Add(currentWeather);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Here's the entity classes:

```
 public class CurrentWeather
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LocalObservartionTime { get; set; }
        public int EpochTime { get; set; }
        public string WeatherText { get; set; }
        //additional props here

        public virtual Temperature Temperature { get; set; }
    }

    public class Temperature
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //relationship
        public int CurrentWeatherId { get; set; }

        //relationship
        public virtual ICollection<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }
    }

    public class Measurement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public int UnitType { get; set; }

        //relationship
        public int TemperatureId { get; set; }
        public virtual Temperature Temperature { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and then  _dataContext.CurrentWeather.Add(weather);    thejson gets serialized fine thers no problem there. th e proble is that when writing to db only main table gets the data